# Tympanus Page Loading Effect: Multiple pages

Tags: javascript, singlepage

I would like to use Tympanus' page loading effects (see demo: http://tympanus.net/Development/PageLoadingEffects/index2.html).

Unfortunately, all demo links only use one page switch, e.g. from page-1 to page-2.
In my case, I would like to have several "pages", one for every project.

Tympanus' example looks for a class called "container" and adds/removes a "show" class to the respective div element.

```
<script>
        (function() {
            var pageWrap = document.getElementById( 'pagewrap' ),
                pages = [].slice.call( pageWrap.querySelectorAll( 'div.container' ) ),
                currentPage = 0,
                triggerLoading = [].slice.call( pageWrap.querySelectorAll( 'a.pageload-link' ) ),
                loader = new SVGLoader( document.getElementById( 'loader' ), { speedIn : 300, easingIn : mina.easeinout } );

            function init() {
                triggerLoading.forEach( function( trigger ) {
                    trigger.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                        ev.preventDefault();
                        loader.show();
                        // after some time hide loader
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            loader.hide();

                            classie.removeClass( pages[ currentPage ], 'show' );
                            // update..
                            currentPage = currentPage ? 0 : 1;
                            classie.addClass( pages[ currentPage ], 'show' );

                        }, 2000 );
                    } );
                } );    
            }

            init();
        })();
    </script>
```

How can I adapt the script in order to be able to have more than just two "pages"?
PS: I write "pages" because it actually all happens in one single html file.

Answer (score 0):

They just flip back and forth between pages here:

```
  currentPage = currentPage ? 0 : 1;
```

Looking at the code, I believe all you need to do is:

```
 currentPage = currentPage == pages.length - 1 ? 0 : currentPage + 1;
```

Comment: Your proposal leads to the fact, that the pages (2, 3, 4) are opened one after another. But I would like to target them specifically. e.g. link-1 opens div-1, link-2 opens div-2, etc.